# Manually right-censoring (top-coding) data for survival modeling: justified?

Tags: survival, censoring

Say we have survival-time data that has a long right tail. Does it make analytical/statistical sense to set a time limit and then manually right-censor (top-code) all times-to-event that exceed this limit, then use survival analysis techniques to analyze this "censored" data?

The censoring I'm asking about is not due to the actual data collection process. That is, it's not due to participants dropping out prematurely nor to the study ending. It's been decided that participants who are recorded with a time-to-event that seems too long should be capped at a reasonable value and considered to be censored. (This is often called top-coding in non-time applications.)

On the one hand, I could say that this is no different from a study where the study period is significantly shorter than the average time-to-event, and where all participants enter at the start of the study. There will be a whole bunch of participants right censored at the end of the study, sharing the same censoring time. And the censoring time will be highly correlated with the time the participant was in the study.

On the other hand, the studies I've seen this used for were longer than the average time-to-event, and participants entered at different times. So censoring at a particular time-to-event threshold seems to be more correlated and less "random" than actual data-collection-driven (i.e. calendar-time-based) censoring.

Does this make any sense? Is right censoring after the fact, based on time-to-event and not a calendar time, reasonable?

If it matters, I'm thinking of parametric survival models, and thus it seems that how well right censoring is handled depends on how accurately the survival time distribution is modeled.

Comment: This is practically important since the study must be concluded and the survival data analyze before the data set becomes complete.  On certain problems, some events may never occur.

Comment: @MichaelChernick: I've edited the title and first paragraph to make clearer that the censoring is not due to study limits, but rather an after-the-fact top-coding by the analyst at some cut-off point.

Comment: Another reason to apply this kind of right censoring might be due to some kind of 'expected' selective loss to follow-up. Imagine the following: patients are admitted to a hospital which follows up on its patients one year after each visit. This way a readmitted patient might have a follow-up covering several years (maybe even some gaps!), while a patient only admitted once would have only one year until censoring. In short, do not forget the possible **informative censoring** in this right tail of survival times.

Comment: I think this is often done for event-driven clinical trials, i.e. all patients are asked to come in for final visits during, say, May and June (after each having been followed by a variable duration of follow-up). Typically, then any data after the final visit for a patient in this time period is considered right-censored at least for the primary analysis of the trial. This is partially for operational reasons and partially because often the trial intervention will be stopped at the final visit and you do not want to mix up the questions "Does it work?" and "What happens when you stop?".

Comment: OK, it sounds like several folks have said that something similar to this is done under different circumstances. Which I take to mean it's not a bad idea. (I've experimented with doing this with some data I'm working on, varying the time-to-event cutoff, and the results aren't encouraging: I think because it really depends on how accurately you can model the survival times.) Would anyone like to make an answer I can accept? (And why the Close vote?)

Comment: Are you just wondering that their survival times "seem too long", ie that they're outliers or represent measurement error? It may not make any difference to a nonparametric analysis (eg, Cox model).

Comment: @gung: I believe that the justification for this top-coding is the worry that long time-to-events represent measurement error. In the case where I was tempted to use it and in the case I have a writeup on, the analysis was parametric.